# Verify combination of disjoint subsets $C$ and $D$ is onto

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

> Let $C$ and $D$ be disjoint subsets of set $A$ and $f:C \to B$ and $g:D \to B$. Define a function $h(x)$ as follows:
>
> $$
> h(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> f(x),  & \text{if $x \in C$} \\
> g(x), & \text{if $x \in D$}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>
> Determine the validity of the following: if $h$ is onto, then $f$ and $g$ are onto.

I assumed the answer would be true. If $C$ is defined for all $x \in C$ and $D$ is completely defined for all $x \in D$, then surely the union of both sets would produce a new set $A$ that has similar properties.

But this, unfortunately, is not correct. In the solution I am using, the following counter example is presented:

$$
h(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x},  & \text{if $x \le -1$} \\
2x+1, & \text{if $x \gt -1$}
\end{cases}
$$

To me this seems like an onto set. Why is this solution correct?

Comment: I think you are actually validating its inverse.

Comment: In the counterexample you provided, the author is using domain $\mathbb{R}$ and codomain $[-1, \infty)$ with $f(x) = 1/x$ defined on the domain $(-\infty, -1]$ and $g(x) = 2x + 1$ defined on the domain $(1, \infty)$.  While $g(x)$ is surjective (onto), $f(x)$ is not.